# Преобразование строки с валютой в число

Tags: c#

подскажите как можно сделать код лучше?
А именно мне не нравится вот этот кусок кода:

```
double balanceConvert = double.Parse(balanse.Replace("₽", "").Replace(".", ",").Trim());
```

**Вот основной код:**

```
//Получаю данные в таком формате
string balanse = "5000.00 ₽";

//Основной баланс
int baseBalance = 10000;


//конвертирую баланс, для дальнейшего сравнения
double balanceConvert = double.Parse(balanse.Replace("₽", "").Replace(".", ",").Trim());


if (baseBalance > balanceConvert)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[{balanceConvert}] - все норм");
}
else Console.WriteLine($"[{balanceConvert}] - необходимо пополнить баланс");
```

Comment: `double balanceConvert = double.Parse(balanse.Split(' ')[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` ?

Comment: Уже лучше, спасибо)

Comment: double.Parse(currencyValue, NumberStyles.Currency, cultureInfo)

Comment: `double balance` - аж передёрнуло! **Никогда** не используйте вещественные типы: `double`, `float` для хранения денежных величин. Используйте `decimal` (или `long` в долях копеек/центов).

Comment: В воспитательных целях поставлю минус. Так вы лучше осознаете, что `double` для денег приводит к потере как денег, так и репутации.

Comment: спасибо, буду знать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Необходимо использовать NumberFormatInfo, в этом случае ваш код будет удобным для чтения, плюс закроет многие проблемы с валидацией входящих данных, так же рекомендую для манипуляций с деньгами использовать тип данных decimal. Тип double не подходит из-за его неточности.

Пример:

```
    var balanceString = "5000.00 ₽";
    var format = new NumberFormatInfo
    {
        CurrencySymbol = "₽",
        CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2,
        CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".",
        NumberDecimalSeparator = ".",
        CurrencyGroupSeparator = " ",
        NumberGroupSeparator = " "
    };
    var balance = decimal.Parse(balanceString, NumberStyles.Currency, format);
```

Переменную format лучше вынести в приватный, статический член типа.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно так:

```
string balance = "5000.00 ₽";
double balanceConvert = double.Parse(Regex.Replace(balance, "[ ₽]", ""), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```